# Help center page on reduced ads contains old, outdated screenshot of UI for reenabling ads

Tags: bug, user-interface, help-center, privileges-page

The [help center page on reduced advertising](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) contains a screenshot of the UI for reenabling ads in case one wishes to see the full set of ads even after earning the rep to hide most of them. However, that screenshot is outdated, and no longer reflects the current UI for disabling them:

[image: Old UI]

This should be replaced with a screenshot of the current UI for re-enabling ads:

[image: New UI]

Can the help center page please be updated to reflect the UI change?