# Outdated screenshot of set bounty dialogue in Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, help-center, privileges-page

The screenshot of the set bounty dialogue in the [set bounties privilege page of the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) is outdated. The order of the buttons has been reversed:

[image: current screenshot]

Now the *Next* button precedes the *Cancel* link from the left (casing of the link has also changed).

[image: current screenshot of dialogue]

I did find the MSO post of when the page was last updated, posted [on MSO in 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360784).

Comment: Not my downvote, but would it be an idea to gather *all* outdated screenshots in the Help Center in a single question? I guess you can make two dozen of these posts ...

Comment: @Glorfindel don't know, I've been aware of the outdated screenshots for months but didn't post about it. Then Sonic [went ahead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378087) yesterday and I followed his lead because why not. Yesterday I also reported a double bug in 1 post and an experienced contributor told me I should split the reports up, next a CM asked if anything needed to be added. Seems like it's a *no win* either way...

Comment: I found the deleted comment about the "double bug" - I agree with that instance since one fix would have to be made in the code, the other as content (Help Center pages are saved as Posts, just like questions, answers and e.g. tag wikis on Meta.SE). As a staff member, I would probably feel more productive updating the entire Help Center at once rather than having to fix each 'bug' separately. But that's just my two cents ...

Comment: @Glorfindel it's a conundrum, if you notice the screenshot above the word "question" is currently on a line of its own, it doesn't look very good but it requires a code change so that'd warrant a separate post... But posting twice about the same dialogue wouldn't be well received, so this time I'll sit back and let someone smarter sort it out.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I can see why one would downvote this. The only difference is the switching of places between Next and Cancel. It's not like that makes this entire screenshot useless, but at the same time there really isn't any need to update them either. If one was busy updating all screenshots, then yeah go ahead. But to go digging for a screenshot that's ˜98% the same

Comment: @Luuklag if something is outdated it's worth reporting. That's been policy across meta as we know it, be it a typo, a wrong capitalization, a slight pixel misalignment or in this case an outdated element.

Comment: @bad_coder I don't say you're wrong in posting this, but I can see why people downvote this, as they could find it pedantic.

Comment: Apart from consistency, what is the standard / recommended way to do this?

Comment: In [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) (the [design system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_system))? Or more general?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum the question is about help center page not being up to date, not about the design of the bounty dialog.

Comment: I wouldn't be too hard on reports, but will say that most of the help center will likely end up getting completely rewritten anyways in the not-so-distant future. We recently hired a technical writer and have been formalizing documentation standards. By those standards, this screenshot was not necessary to convery anything, so it won't need to be updated anymore in the future. :)

Comment: @animuson thanks for the reply, I was aware stacks style guide needed a refresh as did some site elements deriving from it but didn't know those changes were upcoming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has now been fixed, as the screenshot in the help center page has been removed. Per [staff comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378106/outdated-screenshot-of-set-bounty-dialogue-in-help-center?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1262097_378106):

> [This] screenshot was not necessary to convery *[sic]* anything, so it won't need to be updated anymore in the future.

Comment: Didn't want to see a record of a completed request getting Roomba'd, so posted this answer.

Comment: I agree with the record keeping.