# Change screenshots in /help/privileges/reduced-ads

Tags: feature-request, help-center, wording

In `/help/privileges/reduced-ads`, the screenshots seemed to be old. Please update them such that they match with how they currently appear.

[image]

[image]

Even the instructions need some improvement I suppose. Under "But what if I still want to see those ads?":

> Click on "Edit Profile & Settings", then click on "Preferences". There will be an option for re-enabling these ads, should you wish:

There's no option called *Edit Profile & Settings* now. The user just has to select Settings > Advertisements section > Enable advertisements. Please improve the instructions.

Comment: I already requested this: [Help center page on reduced ads contains old, outdated screenshot of UI for reenabling ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378087/help-center-page-on-reduced-ads-contains-old-outdated-screenshot-of-ui-for-reen)